# Why repeated alarm not working?

Tags: android

I created a calender object and the code is as follows:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(ListDemoActivity.this, Demo1.class);
PendingIntent pi =PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ListDemoActivity.this, 0, intent,0);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,8);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,2);
Log.d("Test", "Current time: " + System.currentTimeMillis() );
Log.d("Test", "Calendar time: " + calendar.getTimeInMillis() );
//calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND,8);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),10*1000,pi);
```

I first tried to trigger alarm after every 10 seconds but the alarm triggered only once.
I also printed current time and new time after addition, but the current time is greater than the new one.

```
12-12 12:57:29.506: D/Test(783): Current time: 1323674849507
12-12 12:57:29.506: D/Test(783): Calendar time: 1323657002506
```

Why code not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set the flag in PendingIntent object creation time.

```
PendingIntent pi =PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ListDemoActivity.this, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: i tried that one also but still alarm triggered only once.
here i am trying to repeat alarm every 2seconds.but not working.

Comment: y u change the calender time?

Comment: i just want to repeat alarm after every 10seconds.now i just created calender object and use 
calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND,10);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(ListDemoActivity.this, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);          
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),10*1000,pi);
but still alarm triggered only once.why this is happening?or there is something wrong in my code.plz help me.

Comment: try with the current time and check it will repeat the alarm or not

Answer (score 2):

If you are using broadcast reciever for catching the pending intent then make sure that you have added this line in your manifest

```
   <receiver android:name="com.example.YourReceiver" android:enabled="true"  android:process=":remote"></receiver>
```

Answer (score 1):

hey i got solution actually i was implementing that code in activity so it was not working.
i tried that one in service class and now its working.